Do files on remote server exist?
I have a database of 1000 events.  Each event has an entity code 1..1000.  Each event may or may not have an associated .jpg file, which is stored on a remote server.  If it exists, it is named nnnn.jpg, so event 467 has 0467.jpg .
I need to test, frequently, whether each event has its .jpg on that server or not.
If the .jpg exists, it returns a response code of 200; if it does not, some other response code is returned.
I test this in a loop:
resp1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urt, {muteHttpExceptions: true, followRedirects: false});
resp2 = resp1.getResponseCode();

where urt is the full path including each file name 0001.jpg to 1000.jpg
This takes a great deal of processing time, which can be shortened by skipping items where we already know the answer, but still the processing time is very long and often aborts, presumably due to over-use.
I have looked for a solution involving fetchAll() but I do not quite understand how.  If I had an array 1..1000 of response codes, the rest of the processing would be easy.
resp1 = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll({muteHttpExceptions: true, followRedirects: false}).getResponseCode();

fails on Exception: The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for UrlFetchApp.fetchAll. error

UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(loc, {muteHttpExceptions: true, followRedirects: false}).getResponseCode();
Sorry.  Left out loc in the example where loc is the remote url, but still the same error

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can [edit] your question to fix omitted details and make other improvements.

The fetchAll method returns UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse[]. So, it is required to process the returned value as an array. You can see the official document of it at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object) . Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation because of my poor English skill. So, in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your current whole script using resp1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urt, {muteHttpExceptions: true, followRedirects: false});? By the way, what does loc is the remote url mean?

Thank you for your reply and I apologise for late response.  It is entirely my fault that I cannot completely understand this: your English is excellent.  It is my understanding of gs that is poor.
You asked for the whole script.  It works, but takes 30-50 seconds of run time.  It seems to be too long to paste into a comment, so I'm not sure how to post it.

You can edit your question for this purpose.
